# I want to print the Json response coming from server with - AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I'm working in university project with angularJs(front end) and spring boot(Back end).

I want to print the result coming from the server as "device Name" list.

this is my Json responce.

```
[{"deviceId":5,"deviceName":"test1","hardwareId":"0A0027000008 ","isActive":true,"deviceIp":"192.168.2.22","creationDate":"2018-02-19T05:24:12.000+0000","lastModifiedDate":"2018-02-19T05:24:12.000+0000","customer":{"customerId":1,"customerName":"gjhvjhvh","email":"default@gmail.com","password":"$2a$10$6XkgjN3DUPwrYbsGRcPW8Obe1UPK1jZ1fkDe9EaMQNkd5IKZeVwYi","active":true,"creationDate":"2018-02-13T07:52:33.000+0000","lastModifiedDate":"2018-02-13T07:52:33.000+0000","roles":{"id":2,"role":"CUSTOMER"}}},{"deviceId":4,"deviceName":"test1","hardwareId":"0A0027000007 ","isActive":true,"deviceIp":"192.168.2.36","creationDate":"2018-02-19T05:23:57.000+0000","lastModifiedDate":"2018-02-19T05:23:57.000+0000","customer":{"customerId":1,"customerName":"gjhvjhvh","email":"default@gmail.com","password":"$2a$10$6XkgjN3DUPwrYbsGRcPW8Obe1UPK1jZ1fkDe9EaMQNkd5IKZeVwYi","active":true,"creationDate":"2018-02-13T07:52:33.000+0000","lastModifiedDate":"2018-02-13T07:52:33.000+0000","roles":{"id":2,"role":"CUSTOMER"}}}]
```

this is my codes which prints whole result coming from the server.

HomeService.js

```
'use strict';

App.service('HomeService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){


var REST_SERVICE_URI = '/customer';




this.getDeviceList = function getDeviceList(){
    return $http.get(REST_SERVICE_URI + '/get_device_list')

}

}]);
```

HomeController.js

```
'use strict';


App.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'HomeService', function($scope, HomeService) {


$scope.getDeviceList = function () {
        HomeService.getDeviceList()
          .then (function success(response){ 
              $scope.details = responce.data;
              $scope.errorMessage = '';
          },
          function error(response){
              $scope.errorMessage = 'Error occured!!!';
              $scope.details = response.data.message;
        });
    }

}]);
```

in the Ui

```
 <span>
        <button id="button" name="button" class="btn btn-primary"   ng-click="getDeviceList()" >Show Devices</button>
        {{details}}
        {{errorMessage}}
</span>
```

but I don't know how to filter the Json response.

Comment: show us your code

Comment: based on what you want to fiter?

Comment: I want to filter only deviceNames as a list. @RahulSharma

Comment: In ng-repeat give item.deviceName or filter Devicename in one array and print that.

Comment: @SangramBadi I've updated my quection

Comment: @Tharuka please check my answer and let me know

Comment: i am upvoting you

Comment: @SangramBadi thank you. your answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $scope.getDeviceList = function () {
            HomeService.getDeviceList()
              .then (function success(response){ 
                  $scope.details = [];
                  angular.forEach(response.data, function(value, key) {
                    $scope.details.push(value.deviceName);
                  });
                  $scope.errorMessage = '';
              },
              function error(response){
                  $scope.errorMessage = 'Error occured!!!';
                  $scope.details = response.data.message;
            });
        }
```

You need to push your required value in to an array then you can iterate the value at ui.

```
    <button id="button" name="button" class="btn btn-primary"   ng-click="getDeviceList()" >Show Devices</button>
        <loop ng-repeat="d in details track by $index">{{d}}<br/></loop>
        {{errorMessage}}
```

**OR**

instead of change in controller only change in your ui

```
<button id="button" name="button" class="btn btn-primary"   ng-click="getDeviceList()" >Show Devices</button>
            <loop ng-repeat="d in details track by $index">{{d.deviceName}}<br/></loop>
            {{errorMessage}}
```

Comment: which one you are using 1st setp or 2nd step ?

Comment: I used only 2n'd step

Answer (score 0):

```
    Suppose this is service call in your application:   
     updatePerson: function() {
                        var url = 'your url';
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        $http.get(url).then(function(data) {
                            deferred.resolve(data.data);
                        }, function(error) {
                            deferred.reject(error);
                        });
                        return deferred.promise;
                    },
    Then use it inside controller with factory name (suppose fact is your factory name):
    fact.updatePerson().then(function(data){
      //here data is the response from your server, store it in some scope var
      $scope.responseData= data;
    });
   on UI do..
   <div ng-repeat="item in responseData">{{item.deviceName}}</div>
```

Comment: But its mentioned "device Name" list in the question not the entire response.

Comment: You've to iterate through array of objects too. to access individual deviceName

Comment: There are multiple device objects in the list as a response. Check again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165391/discussion-between-laxman-pai-and-bimlendu-kumar).

Comment: this is collection of devices for the particular customer id.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking only for the devicenames, use below code.

```
            var devicelist = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
                devicelist.push($scope.data[i].deviceName);
            }
            console.log(devicelist);
```

Comment: can you explain with details. @Rakesh Burbue

Comment: you have your main data in $scope.data. You are looping through all the items in it and pushing the deviceName in the devicelist array.

Comment: let me update my question with  codes which print whole result coming from the server.